# non-linearity of median - proof

Tags: proof-verification, median

I'd like to show counterexamples for:

a. $med(X+Y) = med(X) + med(Y)$

b. $med(aX+b) = a\cdot med(X) + b$.

1. Showing that "a" is not correct:

Let $X, Y$ be independent random variables with exponential distribution and correspondeing: $F(t) = 1-e^{-t}$ (for $t \ge 0$).

To find the median I solve $F(t)=1-e^{-t}=1/2$ and then I see $med(X)+med(Y)=2log(2)$.

Now I'd like to take a look at $F_{X+Y}(t)$ - how can I get this function?

2. Showing that "b" is not correct:

For showing this I need $F_{aX}(t)$ and $F_{aX+b}(t)$, correct? Well then I should await some answers to "1.", since I am stuck there.

Comment: For (a) it would be easier to take $X$ and $Y$ to be Bernoulli random variables. If you really want to do it your way, the sum of two i.i.d. exponential r.v.'s is an Erlang (or gamma) r.v. I don't think you can find a counterexample for (b), I'm pretty sure it's actually true.

Comment: @Rahul Thank you! How would I do it using Bernoulli r.v.?

Comment: You take $X$ and $Y$ to be Bernoulli random variables, then compute $\operatorname{med}(X) + \operatorname{med}(Y)$ and $\operatorname{med}(X+Y)$. Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: It's again the part $med(X+Y)$. For $med(X), med(Y)$ I get: $med(X)=1=med(Y)$ iff $q<p$ where $P(X=1=p$ and $P(X=0)=q$. The distribution for $X+Y$ should be a binomial distribution, right? So the distributional function is $F_{X+Y}(t) = P(X+Y\leq t)=\sum_{k=0}^t \binom{2}{k}\cdot p^k \cdot q^{2-k}$.?

Comment: That sounds right. Pick a value, say $p=0.4$, and then you can work out $F_{X+Y}(t)$ for $t=0,1,2$ numerically and observe where the median lies.

Comment: @Rahul Alright, then: $F_{X+Y}(0)=0.36$; $F_{X+Y}(1)=0.84$; finally $F_{X+Y}(2)=1$. Then $med(X+Y)=0.84$?.

Comment: The median is the smallest value of $t$ for which $F(t)\ge1/2$. In this case, $\operatorname{med}(X+Y)=1$ because $F_{X+Y}(1)=0.84\ge0.5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part (a)

Your calculation of the sum of the medians of $X$ and $Y$ is correct and gives $2\ln2\approx1.3863$.

As you say the next step is to get the distribution for $X+Y$. The prob that $X+Y\le t$ is $\int_{r=0}^te^{-t}\int_{s=0}^{t-r}e^{-s}\ ds\ dr=\int_0^te^{-r}(1-e^{r-t}\ dr=1-e^{-t}-te^{-t}$.

You can either solve $1-e^{-t}-te^{-t}=\frac{1}{2}$ numerically to find $t=1.6784$, or you can note that the function is increasing and less than $\frac{1}{2}$ at $t=2\ln2$.

Part (b)

Hint: why would you expect this to be incorrect? You have $X\le m$ iff $aX+b\le am+b$.

Comment: Thank's a lot. To Part(b): If $m$ is $med(aX+b)$ this means that $P(aX+b \leq m) \ge 1/2$ right?  Then how can I use $X \leq m iff aX+b \leq am +b$ as you wrote to proof it?

Comment: $m$ is the median of $X$ if prob $X\le m$ is 0.5. But if prob $X\le m$ is 0.5 then the prob $aX+b\le am+b$ is 0.5, so $am+b$ is the median of $aX+b$.